# Azure will support postgressql+cussandra hybrid database

Tags: database, azure

My question is will azure supports two databases in one virtual machine(postgrssql+cussandra),because my application need both databases.so want to deploy in azure ,any possible solution for that..

Answer (score 0):

You are free to deploy whatever you want on Virtual Machines so yes, it will work.
For Postgres you can also consider managed offering Azure Database For Postgres.

Comment: hi thanks for info. Actually i am looking hybrid database but azure will give you either postgressql or cusandra in different machines , i need both database in one place because we need azure/cloud managed databases